# Georeferencer Plugin: Installed but does not appear in raster menu (QGIS 10.3, Windows 10)

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, georeferencing, windows-10

I see that others have had problems finding a rouge georeferencer window, or using the plugin. But when my student tries to use the confirmed installed georeferencer plugin in QGIS 3.10 on Windows 10 no plugin appears in the raster menu. Any thoughts?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it might seem simple: but can you confirm that the plugin is check marked in the plugins manager? I just tested, if it is isn't marked (even if installed initially) the Georeferencer does not show in the settings/Raster tab.

[image]

Comment: This was indeed the problem. My student may have inadvertently uncheck the plugin. Thanks for your quick reply!